# How to document mail setup after hand-over

Tags: documentation, specifications

I've just moved a client's email services over from my host to Google Apps.  I would like to hand over a document providing all they (or their agent) need should I not be available etc.

How are such documents normally structured, and what level of detail should they contain?  I know user names and passwords are essential, and instructions on how to manage domains on Google Apps are over the top, but what is a commonly used middle ground?

Comment: If you're done with the project, it's already too late for *good* documentation, IMO. You need to document while you're in process, not after the fact.

Comment: sounds like a make-work project (hope it's billable!): you could just as easily send them some relevant links to the Google Apps documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure how the documents would normally be structured, but in this scenario I would think documenting the following is appropriate...

- administrative usernames and passwords
- guidelines for creating new accounts (e.g. naming conventions)
- changes you made to MX records
- changes you made to DNS
- cautionary statements about making changes to DNS if they have the ability
- links to access their services (e.g. the DNS entries you setup)
- links to Google's client oriented documentation (pop3/imap/smtp instructions etc...)
- links to Google's administrative oriented documentation

One to two pages should be sufficient.  Include a short summary of what Google Apps is and how it is different than hosting your own email or using your ISP's services.

Answer (score 2):

We tend to hand over build guides - if it contains a systematic description of how to build the system from scratch, it's probably got all the essential details. Add an FAQ or links to Google's howtos, and you should be fine.